# Multiple listener vs a singleton who returns value that everyone needs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I am curious to know which one is better in terms of performance;
Multiple instance of listener who listen to an event, or a singleton to handle that listening process and then return only the value for everybody else to use?

Example:

```
 function one(){
     $window.on('scroll',function(e){
        doOne(e.scrollValue);
     }
 }

 function two(){
     $window.on('scroll',function(e){
        doTwo(e.scrollValue);
     }
 }

 function three(){
     $window.on('scroll',function(e){
        doThree(e.scrollValue);
     }
 }
```

or

```
var getScrollValue = (function(){
  var _scrollValue = 0;
  $window.on('scroll',function(e){
    _scrollValue = e.scrollValue;
  })
  return function() {
    return _scrollValue;
  }
})();

doOne(getScrollValue());
doTwo(getScrollValue());
doThree(getScrollValue());
```

Comment: My guess would be the singleton has better performance.  You can test it yourself by measuring the time difference between before and after your test.  Maybe run the test 1000 times to get a significant difference.

Comment: @raduation I guess so, but if so, why would there is this multiple-able listener in the first place? I mean, if the second approach is better, then shouldn't the listener only attachable once?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - you provided all the code!  If you're asking what uses cases there are for multiple listeners, well, maybe different objects want to do different things when the same event happens.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you to take a look at my personal workaround about this :

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('mainCtrl',function($window, $scope){
        $scope.scrollPos = 0;

        $window.onscroll = function(){
            $scope.scrollPos = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop || 0;
            $scope.$apply(); //or simply $scope.$digest();

            /* IMPORTANT NOTE : 
             * As $apply() is actully calling $rootScope.$digest() you can
             * directly use $scope.$digest() instead of $scope.$apply() 
             * for better performance depending on context.
             * Long story short : $apply() will always work but force
             * the dirty checking of all scopes that may cause 
             * perfomance issue. 
             */
        };
    });
```

working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/freezystem/nz6cxz3n/)

Here I'm not calling any function but you can easily do it in the onscroll one depending on `$scope.scrollPos` value.
I think it's a better practice to not set too many listeners.

Comment: is that answer help you in any way ? Do you need some explanation ?